# how to write stored procedure in Visual Fox Pro

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-foxpro

I have a Visual Foxpro Datbase and i am not a programmer of VFP, i have to add a stored procedure, i know where to add stored procedure but i don,t know the syntax for writing simple stored procedure.

if any one help me create a stored procedure which just returns max value of some field from some table, it will help me get on right track. B

```
 USE mydb;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE getmax 

AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  select max(id) from mytable

end
```

Above is sample stored procedure in SQL version

Thanks

Comment: Although I gave a sample, SPs do not have much place in VFP. If you told us the purpose we could suggest better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter these lines in Command window:

```
Open Database YourDBCName
Modify Procedure
```

A code window pops up. That is where you would write your SP code. For example with tableName and fieldName as parameters you could write as:

```
Function GetMax( tcTableName, tcFieldName )
    Local Array laMax[1]
    Select Max( &tcFieldName ) ;
        from (m.tcTableName) ;
        into Array laMax
    Return laMax[1]
Endfunc
```

You could then say for example:

```
result = GetMax( 'Contacts', 'LastName' )
```

PS: Didn't translate your SP sample because it was wrong already.